# React route with multiple layouts, re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new in react. I want my app to have multiple layouts for different pages with react router. The code below was found in https://gist.github.com/avinmathew/e82fe7e757b20cb337d5219e0ab8dc2c

```
// Custom route component
const AppRoute = ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...props} />
    </Layout>
  )} />
)

// Actual routes
<Switch>
  <AppRoute exact path="/foo" layout={MainLayout} component={Foo} />
  <AppRoute exact path="/bar" layout={AltLayout} component={Bar} />
  <AppRoute exact path="/bar2" layout={AltLayout} component={Bar2} />
</Switch>
```

My question is that will the layout be re-rendered after change of pages using same layout, (e.g. from /bar to /bar2)?

Comment: I setup a demo:   https://codesandbox.io/s/k27qn595lo

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/0mk825l9vw, @lipp, if we use Link component, the layout isnt unmounted, but rendered

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Since `Component` is a Layout prop and it changes (between `Bar1` and `Bar2`), it will trigger a new render. React uses virtual DOM to only pass the real changes to real DOM.

Comment: does it means that it makes just a little impact on the performance? comparing to the single layout

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will re-render your layout upon navigating. The reason for this, is that the `render` 'function as a child' AKA '[render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)' (this is a design pattern used within React, that react-router-dom implements) gets called upon navigating to that path.

Also - [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) renders the first child  or  that matches the location.

Try this:

```
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';

const history = createMemoryHistory();

<Router history={history}>
  <Route component={MainLayout}>
    <Route exact path="/foo" component={Foo} />
  </Route>
  <Route component={AltLayout}>
    <Route exact path="/bar" component={Bar} />
    <Route exact path="/bar2" component={Bar2} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: this code seems not working, all layouts will be rendered